# Как реализовать проверку новой роли из панели администратора, laratrust?

Tags: laravel, acl

Изучаю **santigarcor/laratrust**.

Хочу сделать в панели администратора функционал по работе с ролями и разрешениями. Как реализовать CRUD ролей и разрешений понятно, а вот как реализовать динамическую проверку новой роли?

Пример проверки с мануала: `$user->hasRole('admin'); // true`

Как реализовать проверку новой роли из панели администратора, admin2 например?

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем вы проверяете название роли, когда необходимо проверять разрешение у самой роли

Comment: Роль по-сути своей является группой разрешений под одним именем, вы задаете название и выдаете разрешения, на основе которых и будут происходить проверки. Что может админ? - входить в админ-панель, так и выдайте ему разрешение и уже его проверяйте.

Answer (score -1):

`'admin'` - это переменная типа string, и поэтому мы можем запомнить роль в переменную и затем проверить роль user'a на совпадение.

Если ролей много, то можно каждую роль добавлять в массив, а потом по этому массиву проходиться и искать совпадения.

Comment: Получается чтобы реализовать нужно будет создать как минимум одну таблицу в которой будет список "страниц сайта" с массивом ролей для каждой страницы.<br />Например: Страница "Контакты" |/contacts|['admin','user']  Такое решение не будет костыльным?